# Freeze multiple rows in Excel 2013 with a shared workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel workbook on a Network drive, this Excel workbook is shared amongst multiple users.

When I freeze multiple rows  in place and save the Excel workbook, close it and open it again. The rows are frozen as I expect it to be. But when another user opens the workbook, what they see is that the top row is frozen instead of the multiple rows that I had frozen.

Is this a known bug when working with shared workbooks? - or am I doing something wrong